# Why operator "=" in var declaration lays at different position when different types of objects are declared?

Tags: go

I'm a complete newbie in Go. Trying to learn. I noticed a strange difference between these two declarations:

```
var arr = [3]int {1,2,3}
var i int8 = 5
```

I mean the position of "=" operator. Is there any story behind this that I should know? The first one looks suspicious to me looking from the perspective of C++ programmer. Smells like an assignment of a temporary object, that is created, then copied to the left-hand destination.
Could someone clarify this? Is there any perfomance-related issue?

Comment: Oh... I see I could also say "var j int8 = int8(5)"  and "var arr [3]int = [3]int {1,2,3}" Now it looks consistent. thanks @ThinkGoodly; If You put this info into answer I will accept and vote up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the variable in the first statement is inferred from the value. The type of the variable in the second statement is specified explicitly. There is no runtime performance difference based on how the type is determined at compile time.

The = sign is in the same position in both [variable declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations): before the value

Any difference in the performance of the two statements is a consequence of the different types and values used.

The first declaration can be written with an explicit type, but it's more verbose than needed:

```
var arr [3]int = [3]int{1,2,3}
```

The second declaration can be written with an inferred type:

```
var i = int8(5)
```

Answer (score 2):

The Go specs define the [variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations) as follows:

`VarDecl     = "var" ( VarSpec | "(" { VarSpec ";" } ")" ) .`

`VarSpec     = IdentifierList ( Type [ "=" ExpressionList ] | "=" ExpressionList ) .`

This means that between `var myIdent` and the `=` sign there may or may not be an explicit type.

Furthermore:

> If a type is present, each variable is given that type. Otherwise, each variable is given the type of the corresponding initialization value in the assignment.

This is especially relevant when the assigned value is an untyped constant: for example in `var x = 5` the literal `5` is untyped, therefore (quote) "it is first implicitly converted to its default type". In case of an integer constant, the default value is `int`.

Instead in `var x int8 = 5`, `x` is effectively an `int8`.